# Axios withCredentials customize which http cookie to send

Tags: node.js, cookies, axios, cookie-httponly

Suppose on server side you set 2 httpOnly cookies (accesstoken & refreshtoken)
you want to pass accesstoken to all of the frontend requests
but only pass refreshtoken to /RefreshToken endpoint.

I can see in axios withCredential: true flag allows for all httponly cookies to be passed to server, but is there a way to customize this to a specific cookie ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't how `httpOnly` cookies work.  You don't get to access them or decide which gets sent from the browser.

It seems like your server-side code for the `/RefreshToken` route can easily just ignore the `accessToken` cookie and only pay attention to the `refreshToken` cookie.  That's entirely up to your server code so you can just code it accordingly.

> but is there a way to customize this to a specific cookie ?

No, not for `httpOnly` cookies.  They are `httpOnly` for a reason - the client can't mess with them in any way.

Comment: I know I can ignore them server side, I just wanted to prevent refreshToken being sent everywhere to minimize potential risk for replay attacks...
*No, not for httpOnly cookies. They are httpOnly for a reason - the client can't mess with them in any way.*
That`s what I dont get, If the client cannot mess with them, then how come axios can omit passing them to an endpoint (if withCredentials flag is set to false ) ?

Comment: @Phil15 = You can send all or none - that's it for `httpOnly` cookies.  You aren't even allowed in the client to know if it exists or what its value is.  The entire point of an `httpOnly` cookie is to limit client-side code access to the cookie.  There are probably other ways to protect from replay attacks, but that would be a different question and would have to disclose much more about what you're trying to protect from.  You seem to want an answer that does not exist - that just isn't how the browser works.  Find a different way to accomplish your objective.